# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {})

Tags: reactjs

I am sending through `socket.io` an object to a `react` application like this:

```
function getApiAndEmit(socket, quote) 
{
    try 
    {
        var { ticker, type, price, size, timestamp } = quote;
        socket.emit("FromAPI", quote);
        //console.log(ticker, type, price, size, timestamp)
    } 
    catch (error) 
    {
        console.error(`Error: ${error.code}`);
    }
};
```

When I try to render it on the client side, I get the error:

```
If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons.
```

**What is the correct way to render the fields on the web browser with `react`?**

The code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      response: {},
      endpoint: "http://127.0.0.1:4001"
    };
  }

componentDidMount() {
    const { endpoint } = this.state;
    const socket = socketIOClient(endpoint);
    socket.on("FromAPI", data =>  this.setState({ response: data }));
  }

render() {
    const { response } = this.state;
    return (
      <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
        {response
          ? <ul>
              Quote: {response}
            </ul>
          : <p>Loading...</p>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

React can't render objects. To bypass the error immediately, put in the following:

```
{
    response
        ? <ul><li>Quote: {JSON.stringify(response)}</li></ul>
        : <p>Loading...</p>
}
```

#### If `response` is an array of Strings:

```
<ul>Quote: { response.map((item, index) => (<li key={index}>{item}</li>)) }</ul>
```

#### If `response` is an array of objects:

```
<ul>Quote: { response.map((item, index) => (<li key={index}>{item.quote}</li>)) }</ul>
```

#### If `response` is an object:

```
<ul><li>Quote: {response.quote}</li></ul>
```